# Is there a way to test Observable subscription in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, testbed

I'm new to angular, trying to write unit test case for the below function.

**HomeComponent.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.YesNo = [
          { label: 'Yes', value: 'Yes' },
          { label: 'No', value: 'No' },
        ];
 
        this.cols = [
          { field: 'Human', header: 'name', width: '5' },
          { field: 'MaritalStatus', header: 'Marital Status', width: '8' },
      ];
        this.getAllAccounts();
      });
  }
```

I tried the below test case, but I'm not sure how to cover **YesNo**, **cols** , **getAllAccounts**()

**HomeComponent.spec.ts**

```
class MockUserService {
    inProgress = of("Login");
  }
  describe('AccountComponent', () => {
    let UserService;
    let comp;
    let userService;
    let testInteractionStatus: InteractionStatus.None;
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          {
            provide: UserService,
            useClass: MockUserService
          },
          MsalService,
          MsalGuard,
          MsalBroadcastService,
          MessageService,
          HomeService,
          HomeComponent
      ],
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
        declarations: [
            HomeComponent
        ],
      }).compileComponents();
    });
  it('should test....', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    app.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(userService.inProgress.YesNo).toBeDefined();
    expect(userService.inProgress.YesNo).toBeDefined();

  });
```

- Angular Version

Angular CLI: 12.2.6
Node: 14.17.6
Package Manager: npm 7.23.0
OS: darwin x64

Comment: Mock a subscription or test a subscription? Mocking, it looks like you are already doing for userService right?

Comment: Do you want to test that the subscription is done or do you want to test that the result in right after receiving the value ? If I were you, I would extract the code in the subscription block in a dedicated method, making it easier to test

Comment: @SrikarPhaniKumarMarti I'm testing the subscription but it's not working as expected. I did try to mock as well, still it didn't work. Appreciated any help here.  I'm getting error like "Expected undefined to be defined.
ERRO : "Expected undefined to be defined"

Comment: Can you please send me what that subscription response would look like? I can help you once I see that

Comment: can I know how to capture subscription response ? @SrikarPhaniKumarMarti

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like npm's [rxjs-marbles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-marbles) or [jasmine-marbles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-marbles) to test different values being emitted from your observable.

Within the test suite you can subscribe to your observable. Once the observable has emitted you would do:

```
expect(component.yesNo).toHaveLength(2) // this is pseudo code, actual code may vary
```

Notice currently you are testing the home component but within the tests for the home component are expecting the service to have something set. Unit testing is about isolating external dependencies so that you only ever test the component itself.

So you do not expect the service value to be anything. Instead, you mock the service and expect the component value to be something.

Regarding testing `getAllAccounts()` you would create a spy and expect that it has been called.

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample code snippet to try ?

Answer (score 1):

@itgeek, you can do the following to capture the subscription response:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe((data: any) => { <<< ADD THIS LINE >>>
        console.log('Subscription Response ==>', data); << ADD THIS LINE >>
        this.YesNo = [
          { label: 'Yes', value: 'Yes' },
          { label: 'No', value: 'No' },
        ];
 
        this.cols = [
          { field: 'Human', header: 'name', width: '5' },
          { field: 'MaritalStatus', header: 'Marital Status', width: '8' },
      ];
        this.getAllAccounts();
      });
  }
```

Once you do that in your console, you should be able to see the response

Comment: Thanks i figured the way to fix the issue.

Comment: ...AND? Please, if you figure out a solution to the question you posted, share it with us. There's nothing worse than finding someone with the same issue as yours and then they update it with "never mind figured it out".